# Dynamically generated table not taking auto page if data exceeds

Tags: php, fpdf

I am generating Invoice using fpdf as in the example [FPDF - Invoice](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex20.pdf)

I have many number of line items in a single invoice. If it exceeds page 1 , it has to go to next page automatically by keeping the table format intact, which is not happening in this.

Can somebody plz suggest me on this?

Here is the code i am generating pdf

```
$cols=array( "HSN/SAC"    => 17,
             "Description"     => 45,
             "Price"      => 15,
             "Qty" => 13,
             "Disc%"          => 10,
             "Taxable Amt"    => 20,

              );
$pdf->addCols( $cols);
$cols=array( "HSN/SAC"    => "L",
             "Description"     => "L",
             "Price"      => "L",
             "Qty" => "L",
             "Disc%"          => "L",
             "Taxable Amt"    => "L",

            );
$pdf->addLineFormat( $cols);
$pdf->addLineFormat($cols);

$y    = 133;
$tamt1 =0;
$iamt =0;
 $qty1 = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ 
$desc =  $row['description'] ;

$total = $row['sub_total']+$row['tax_amount'];   
$line = array( "HSN/SAC"    => "".$row['hsn_sac']."",   
               "Description"     => "".$row['name']." - ". html_entity_decode(strip_tags($desc)) ,
               "Price"      => "".$row['selling_price']."",
               "Qty"  => "".$row['quantity']."",
               "Disc%"          => "".$row['discount']."",
               "Taxable Amt"          => "".number_format(($row['total']),2)."",

               );
$size = $pdf->addLine( $y, $line );
$y   += $size + 10;


$total_amt += $row['total']; 
 $tax_amt += $row['tax_amount'];
 $qty1 += $row['quantity'];
}
```

Here is the `addCols` function

```
function addCols( $tab )
{
    global $colonnes;

    $r1  = 9;
    $r2  = $this->w - ($r1 * 1.9) ;
    $y1  = 120;
    $y2  = $this->h - 60 - $y1;
    $this->SetXY( $r1, $y1 );

    $this->Rect( $r1, $y1, $r2, $y2, "D");
    $this->Line( $r1, $y1+6, $r1+$r2, $y1+7);
    $colX = $r1;
    $colonnes = $tab;
    while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($tab) )
    {
        $this->SetXY( $colX, $y1+2 );
        $this->SetFont( "", "B", 7);
        $this->Cell( $pos, 2, $lib, 0, 0, "C");
        $colX += $pos;
        $this->SetFont( "", "", 7);
        $this->Line( $colX, $y1, $colX, $y1+$y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing code you've tried so far.

Comment: I have added the code.